# The complement of $\Gamma$ is an open connected set whose boundary is precisely $\Gamma$.

Tags: complex-analysis

In Stein & Shakarchi's Complex Analysis text, it says

> Let $\Gamma$ be curve in the plane that is simple and piecewise
> smooth. Then, the complement of $\Gamma$ is an open connected set
> whose boundary is precisely $\Gamma$.

How is this possible? For example, let's say circle is a simple and piecewise-smooth curve. Then interior and exterior of it are open, so complement of circle is disconnected.

Comment: Of course, this is false. May there is a typo in the book.

Comment: I was thinking maybe by complement they mean connected component of complement?

Comment: Yes  the boundary of each component is $\Gamma$.